# How to write a paper where a chemical compound's name cannot be disclosed?

Tags: publications, chemistry

I am currently working with a certain chemical compound whose name its very well known and largely studied. However, due to my findings that relate this compound with an industrial procedure (that cannot be patented), I am not able to mention its name in a possible manuscript.

My question is if anybody knows about publications that somehow avoid to mention the name of a chemical compound due to industrial secrecy from which I could guide my thoughts towards writing such a manuscript.

Comment: What is your manuscript going to be about?  If you're describing some experiment that uses the compound, it's hard to imagine why any journal would want to publish a paper that doesn't include enough information to reproduce the experiment.

Comment: The compound is found during the development of a plant, and the industrial application is the elucidation of the seasons in which they can yield the maximum of this compound from the plant. As a side history of this analysis, I found that it confirms the effect of abiotic factors in the plant's development, so is not directly related with an experiment or new method. Rather, an unexpected result

Comment: It may be useful to read these related questions about confidential research: [Academic literature on the construction of Dangerous Things](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/73551/academic-literature-on-the-construction-of-dangeous-things), [Using Leaked Proprietary Information in Scientific Paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93965/using-leaked-proprietary-information-in-scientific-paper), [Confidentiality of Thesis Data: PhD with Industrial Partner](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27991/confidentiality-of-thesis-data-phd-with-industrial-partner)

Comment: I guess the question would be, is the result going to be scientifically interesting or useful to a reader, without identifying the compound? Can a researcher make sense of the result, and be convinced that it is valid, without knowing what the compound is?

Comment: My ex did a confidential final year project and it is still held confidential... Ok so I formatted and proof-read it but it is not publicly svailable...